# JSON Redshift SQL - Iterate through array of json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, amazon-redshift

I don't find a solution to query an array of json object with redshift.
For each row, I have an array of json object stored in a column as the following:

`[{'a':x,'b':y,'type':z},{'a':x,'b':y,'type':w},{'a':x,'b':y,'type':z},{a:x,b:y,type:z}]`

For each row, I want to extract the number of 'type' z object in a new column.
Anyone would have an idea?

Thanks a lot,

Nicolas

Comment: Check out this question...the user defined function bits might be appropriate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979669/expand-a-json-data-into-new-columns-in-a-generic-fashion-in-redshift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this syntax to loop through json arrays in redshift fields.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE seq
(i int); INSERT INTO seq VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);

SELECT distinct 
json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(yourfieldname, seq.i),'type') as type
FROM yourtablename, seq AS seq
--- arman why is this less than the array
WHERE seq.i < JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(yourfieldname)

;

DROP TABLE seq;
```